# How to fix Deprecated Gradle when building apk releases is react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle

When there is no error in the developer process but when I want to Build APK release on react native an error occurs ?.

I have tried clean gradle but it still has errors and gradle native still depracated

````
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2m 1s
51 actionable tasks: 51 executed ```

I expectd for a solution so that the Build Release APK can react natively.
````

Comment: ok it was fix it because I use Svg file. Can i Ask how to fix svg not showing in production react native. I use library react-native-remote-svg